# How to convert JSON timestamp to time using Jinja?

Tags: json, timestamp, jinja2, iso8601

I have this simple JSON:

```json
{
     "ts": "2022-07-17T09:24:21.840227"
}
```

and I would like to know what date it is using Jinja.

I tried these two variations:

- ```
  {{ ts | iso8601_to_time | datetimeformat('%a, %B %d %Y, %H:%M:%S') }}
  ```
- ```
  {{ ts | timestamp_to_time | datetimeformat('%a, %B %d %Y, %H:%M:%S') }}
  ```

but both of them are throwing actual time.

I would expect something like this:

```
Sun, July 17 2022, 09:24:17
```

How can I achieve this format?

Comment: `iso8601_to_time`, `timestamp_to_time` and `datetimeformat` are not standard filters of Jinja, could you [edit] your question and add what framework you are using Jinja with?

Comment: Well, I don't know where to find framework. We worn in a quite complex program called "TEA", I think it is internal too, anyways, all I need is some suggestion what to use for representing time format correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out in a meanwhile:
**{% set myDate = ts | split('.') %}

{% set myDateFinal = myDate[0]+'Z' %}

{{ myDateFinal | strtotime("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX") | datetimeformat('%a, %B %d %Y, %H:%M:%S') }}**
Basically:

- Split by "." sign (makes array of what is left[0] and right[1] from dot)
  [2022-07-17T09:24:21, 840227]
- Look at the first (left) part and add "Z" sign
  2022-07-17T09:24:21Z
- Do some magic
  Done!